# Why do my svg look so bad?

Tags: google-chrome, svg, adobe-illustrator

My svg looks very bad in Google Chrome and Firefox too, the Svg borders have poor quality:

[image]

Meanwhile, in Illustrator the svg looks awesome:

[image]

I have saved the .svg file with this configuration:

[image]

What is happened?

Comment: What do you mean by "bad"?  It looks okay to me.  What do you feel is wrong with it?

Comment: "Bad" mean that Svg border have poor quality, for example: http://blog.rockymountaintraining.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/Photoshop_ss_005.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your SVG has a lot of horizontal and/or vertical lines, you can improve its appearance by aligning the coordinates to the pixel grid. I'll give you an example:

[image: Effects of pixel alignment in SVGs]

Here are three SVG images made of rounded rectangles. (The source code for these images is pasted below.)

- In (A), the rectangle coordinates aren't aligned to the pixel grid at all. As a result, some of the lines are clear and sharp while others are fuzzy and a bit darker.
- In (B), the rectangle coordinates are snapped to integer values, giving them a uniform appearance. However, they all look fuzzy now, because the antialiasing spreads each line across a width of two pixels.
- In (C), the coordinates are snapped to integer values *and* given an additional offset of 0.5 pixels in the x and y directions. You should be able to see a definite improvement here.

If you're working in Illustrator, try viewing your artwork at 100% in "Pixel Preview" mode.

I would also recommend not using stroke widths smaller than 1 pixel. If you want to simulate thinner lines, try reducing the opacity instead.

```html
<svg width="200" height="150" viewBox="0 0 200 150">
  <!-- (Original drawing) -->
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="150" fill="#47f" stroke="none" />
  <g fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1.2">
    <rect x="20.1" y="20.1" width="160" height="110" rx="50" ry="50"/>
    <rect x="25.3071" y="25.3071" width="149.5857" height="99.5857" rx="44.7929" ry="44.7929"/>
    <rect x="30.5143" y="30.5143" width="139.1714" height="89.1714" rx="39.5857" ry="39.5857"/>
    <rect x="35.7215" y="35.7215" width="128.7571" height="78.7571" rx="34.3785" ry="34.3785"/>
    <rect x="40.9286" y="40.9286" width="118.3428" height="68.3428" rx="29.1714" ry="29.1714"/>
  </g>
  <text x="100" y="80" text-anchor="middle" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="20" fill="#fff">(A)</text>
</svg>
<svg width="200" height="150" viewBox="0 0 200 150">
  <!-- (Lines snapped to integer coordinates) -->
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="150" fill="#47f" stroke="none" />
  <g fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1.2">
    <rect x="20" y="20" width="160" height="110" rx="50" ry="50"/>
    <rect x="25" y="25" width="150" height="100" rx="45" ry="45"/>
    <rect x="30" y="30" width="140" height="90" rx="40" ry="40"/>
    <rect x="35" y="35" width="130" height="80" rx="35" ry="35"/>
    <rect x="40" y="40" width="120" height="70" rx="30" ry="30"/>
  </g>
  <text x="100" y="80" text-anchor="middle" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="20" fill="#fff">(B)</text>
</svg>
<svg width="200" height="150" viewBox="0 0 200 150">
  <text x="100" y="80" text-anchor="middle" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="20" fill="#fff">(A)</text>
  <!-- (Lines snapped to integer coordinates with 0.5px offset) -->
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="150" fill="#47f" stroke="none" />
  <g fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1.2">
    <rect x="20.5" y="20.5" width="160" height="110" rx="50" ry="50"/>
    <rect x="25.5" y="25.5" width="150" height="100" rx="45" ry="45"/>
    <rect x="30.5" y="30.5" width="140" height="90" rx="40" ry="40"/>
    <rect x="35.5" y="35.5" width="130" height="80" rx="35" ry="35"/>
    <rect x="40.5" y="40.5" width="120" height="70" rx="30" ry="30"/>
  </g>
  <text x="100" y="80" text-anchor="middle" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="20" fill="#fff">(C)</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your "bad" example, the SVG has been reduced to roughly half size. That means some of the lines that are approx 1 pixel thick in your "good" example are now only around 0.5 pixels thick.  That doesn't give the anti-aliasing routines in the SVG renderer much to play with.  Try making the stroke widths thicker.

You should get better results then.