# .SVG rendering Chrome pixelated

Tags: google-chrome, svg, responsive-design, svg-filters

**Why is Chrome rendering so badly?**
What am I doing wrong?

PNG fallback for chrome can't be the only solution for this right??

[image: Chrome pixelated the slanting lines]

**This is how I save the file:**
[image]

Comment: They look very similar to me. However, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31293804/1679849) might help you improve the appearance of your SVG.

Comment: Thanks for the link and I think its that problem. When I look in illustrator at the image in pixel and 100% the slanting lines are a bit blurry but I don't know how I could fix that without changing the logo to much.

Any idea's?

Comment: You can try shape-rendering="crispEdges" to get rid of anti-aliasing completely, or you can try to add a filter to manipulate the edge opacity using feComponentTransfer & feFuncA

Comment: shape-rendering="crispEdges" makes it more crispy. Searching for a good tutorial for feCompnentTransfer.. issn't much online for this filter technique